# Finding a greatest lower bound for a union of cuts

Tags: real-analysis

Let us define cuts $\alpha_n = \{a \in \mathbb{Q}: a<1-\frac{1}{n}\}$. So for example $\alpha_1 = \{a \in \mathbb{Q}: a<0\}$, $\alpha_2 = \{a \in \mathbb{Q}: a<\frac{1}{2}\}$, $\alpha_3 = \{a \in \mathbb{Q}: a<\frac{2}{3}\}$, and so on...

Now let us define $A$ as the union of all $a_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ($A = \{a_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$).

The Least Upper Bound of $A$ is pretty trivial, but I am having trouble with finding the Greatest Lower Bound. How would anyone go about solving it and proving it?

Comment: Let $\beta=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n$. Now prove that $\beta$ is the least upper bound of $A$. This is a standard technique of finding least upper bound. The greatest lower bound is clearly $0$ or $\alpha_1$. This part is easy as $\alpha_1$ is the least member of $A$.

Comment: Isn't the least upper bound 1?

Comment: Yes the least upper bound is $1$.